# add dynamic input fields to array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, user-input

Apologies if this is the incorrect discussion area.

I am looking for some help on adding multiple user inputs into an array using jquery.

I have a form that dynamically adds and removes fields as shown here (maximum 5 but may not always be 5, minimum 1):
[dynamic inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT9nE.png)

I would like to loop through the course number and description and add to an array. For example:

```
Array 
(
[0] => PT 101, Personal Training 101
[1] => EH 263, Eating Healthy
}
```

I'm currently getting the results this way:

```
var courseInfo = $("input[name='course_num\\[\\]'], input[name='course_desc\\[\\]']").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get().join(",");
```

I have tried .toArray, .get and other methods of getting the values but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two inputs are related and should have the same parent:

```
<div name="parent">
  <input name="course_num" />
  <input name="course_desc" />
</div>
```

Then, your'e selector should be based on the parent:

```
var arr = $("[name='parent']").map(function() {
      return {
        num: $(this).find("input[name='course_num']").val(),
        desc: $(this).find("input[name='course_desc']").val()
      };
  });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mgpk257p/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This seems like a good approach. Unfortunately when I try it I do not get any text from the inputs; only [Object, Object, Object] and undefined. Any thoughts...? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since each item in th array is an object that has `num` and `desc` properties.